# Binary file getting corrupted when trying to download using Struts 6.3.0.2 with Java

Tags: java, download, weblogic12c

When I am trying to download the pdf and doc-x file from my app after upgrading from struts2 to struts 6.3.0.2, the file is getting corrupted. I am not able to open the pdf file when I have downloaded from the app after I uploaded to the app. For the doc-x file it is showing System is unable to process with your request which is the custom error from the errors file. On the console it shows that the file has been downloaded successfully but still the doc-x file cannot be opened.

This is my original code before the upgrade

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public void downloadAttach(){
    try {
        String filename = DotsFormUtil.cleanStringFile(request.getParameter("filename"));
        String realname = DotsFormUtil.cleanStringFile(request.getParameter("name"));

        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
        String strDotsIdToken = (String) session.getAttribute("strDotsIdToken");

        try{
            if(strDotsIdToken == null || !strDotsIdToken.equals(filename.split("_")[0]))
                logger.error("strDotsIdToken is null or strDotsIdToken is not equal and Exception is thrown");
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.info(e);
        }
        try {
            if(filename!= null){
               ServletOutputStream out = null;
               FileInputStream fi = null;
                try {
                    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.dotsDisplay");
                    String strDirectory=DotsFormUtil.cleanpString(bundle.getString("dots.attachments.path"));
                    File f= new File(FilenameUtils.normalize(DotsFormUtil.cleanString(strDirectory+File.separator + filename)));
                    String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}";
                    if(realname.matches(pattern)){

                        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; fileName=" +realname);
                    }
                    response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");

                            out = response.getOutputStream();
                        fi= new FileInputStream(f);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];

                        int readInt=fi.read(buffer);
                        try{
                            if(readInt != -1){
                                out.write(buffer);
                                out.flush();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            logger.info(e);
                        }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.info("File not found error" + filename);
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }catch (IOException e){
                    logger.info("error in reading file:" + filename);
                }finally {
                    if(out != null) safeClose(out);
                    if(fi != null) safeClose(fi);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        logger.info("successfully download attachment file");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

    public static String cleanStringFile(String- aString){
        if(aString==null) return null;
        String cleanString = "";
        char cleanChar = '\0';
        for(int i=0; i<aString.length(); i++){
            cleanChar = cleanCharFile(aString.charAt(i));
            if(cleanChar != '\0') cleanString+=cleanChar;
        }
        return cleanString;
    }

    private static char cleanCharFile(char aChar){
        for(int i = 48; i<58; ++i){
            if(aChar ==i) return (char) i;
        }
        for(int i = 65; i<91; ++i){
            if(aChar ==i) return (char) i;
        }
        for(int i = 97; i<123; ++i){
            if(aChar ==i) return (char) i;
        }

        switch (aChar){
            case '.':
                return '.';
            case '_':
                return '_';
            case '-':
                return '-';
            case '!':
                return '!';
        }
        return '\0';
    }
```

This is my edited code but I am still not able to open the downloaded pdf and doc-x file

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;

    public class getDotsMissionAction {

        public void downloadAttach() {
            // Your existing code...

            try {
                if (filename != null) {
                    try {
                        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.dotsDisplay");
                        String strDirectory =  DotsFormUtil.cleanString(bundle.getString("dots.attachments.path"));
                        File f = new File(strDirectory + File.separator + filename);
                        String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}";
                        if (realname.matches(pattern)) {
                            response.reset();
                            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileName=" + realname);

                            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                                 OutputStream out2 = response.getOutputStream()) {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    out2.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        logger.error(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            logger.info("successfully download attachment file");
        }

        import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        public class getDotsMissionAction {

            public void downloadAttach(HttpServletResponse response) {
                // Your existing code...

                try {
                    if (filename != null) {
                        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.dotsDisplay");
                        String strDirectory = DotsFormUtil.cleanString(bundle.getString("dots.attachments.path"));
                        File f = new File(strDirectory + File.separator + filename);
                        String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}";
                        if (realname.matches(pattern)) {
                            response.reset();
                            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                            // Determine content type based on file extension
                            String contentType;
                            if (realname.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                                contentType = "application/pdf";
                            } else if (realname.toLowerCase().endsWith(".docx")) {
                                contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                            } else {
                                // Add more content types as needed
                                contentType = "application/octet-stream"; // Default to binary
                            }
                            response.setContentType(contentType);
                            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + realname);

                            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                                 OutputStream out2 = response.getOutputStream()) {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    out2.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Handle invalid filename pattern
                            // For example: Log an error, return a response indicating invalid file, etc.
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }
                logger.info("successfully download attachment file");
            }

            // Your other methods...
        }
```

Comment: `out.write(buffer);` should be `out.write(buffer, 0, readInt);`. And don't flush inside the loop. And you don't need a buffer whose size is the size of the file. 8k is sufficient. Just a copy *loop:* `while ((readInt = fi.read(buffer)) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, readInt); }`.

Comment: Hi KJ thank you for your input. So previously before the upgrade my original code was working but now I have reverted back to the original code it is still not working. How do I modify my existing original code?

Comment: user207421 how do I create a copy loop and set the file size to 8k?

Comment: user207421 Is this what you mean?

try{
        
            
            while (readInt = fi.read(buffer) > 0){
                out.write(buffer,0,readInt);
            }
            
            
        }
    catch (Exception e){
        logger.info(e);
    }

Comment: I meant what I wrote. Using it is up to you. Checking whether you’ve perpetrated a typo ditto. The compiler will help. You’re wasting time. These questions are all pointless.

Comment: user207421 when I use a 8k buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int readInt = fi.read(buffer)

try{ while (readInt = fi.read(buffer) > 0){ out.write(buffer,0,readInt); } } catch (Exception e){ logger.info(e); } 

The pdf file still cannot be opened and the docx file on the frontend it shows the customise error.

Comment: user207421 when I a buffer whose size is the size of the file

byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];

I am not getting an error when I am downloading the docx file but when I open the docx file it is an empty file. The pdf file still cannot be opened after downloading

Comment: You will get OOM when the file is large enough, or else if the file is really large the cast to `int` will truncate it. My way this can’t happen. Why are you setting the transfer-encoding to base64 when you aren’t doing any such encoding?

Comment: user207421 the original code was not done by me. It was done by the previous team and they had set the transfer-encoding to base64. Before the upgrade to Struts6.3.0.2, the original code done by the previous team was able to open downloaded pdf and docx file.

Comment: user207421 when I use a 8k buffer byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; int readInt = fi.read(buffer) try{ while (readInt = fi.read(buffer) > 0){ out.write(buffer,0,readInt); } } catch (Exception e){ logger.info(e); } The pdf file still cannot be opened and the docx file on the frontend it shows the customise error even after commenting out transfer-encoding to base64.

Comment: How about you use the code I kindly provided? That isn't it. I didn't say anything about an initial read before the copy loop. All you need is a declaration of `int readInt;`. This is all rather incredible, given that you *already have* a working copy loop in another part of the code.

Comment: user207421
 if I were to just declare int readInt; the he pdf file still cannot be opened and the docx file on the frontend it shows the customise error. I have used the code that you provided try{ while (readInt = fi.read(buffer) > 0){ out.write(buffer,0,readInt); } } catch (Exception e){ logger.info(e); }

Comment: When the docx and pdf files are being downloaded, they become 0 KB.

Comment: Hi user207421 appreciate your assistance
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)8192]
int readInt;
while ((readInt = fi.read(buffer)) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, readInt); }
out.flush

I am still not able to download the pdf file. I can upload the file but not download the pdf file. I have used my original code and commented out the Content-Transfer-Encoding. Appreciate if you could assist.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved by adding the line:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
```